# Plots (ggplot2) in my R markdown slides (xaringan) error when i share in R pubs or just html file

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, xaringan

I'm trying to share mi homework in r markdown slides (with xaringan) through r pubs o just sharing the html file but i realized that the plots looks like:[image: Error un plots] error that doesn't exist in my local machine.

i'm not sure why, but renderized just the r markdown has html works fine.... i guess that there could be something in the script. Also, i leave here the configuration of r chunks that deploy the plots (ggplot)
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify `self_contained:true` to create a standalone html (see [here](https://yihui.org/en/2021/06/self-contained-xaringan/). Otherwise you need to upload the presentation figures as separate files as well.

Comment: Hi!! Thanks for your response, but it didn't work to me